# iOS UIView rounding top corners works just for top left

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to round top corners of UIView. Emulator iOS version 12.0

My extension

```
    extension UIView
{
    func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

How I use it

```
test.round(corners: [.topRight, .topLeft], radius: 20)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: are you sure there is no other view overlapping? try capturing the user interface at runtime

Comment: Have you added any constraint on that `view` ? And where did you call this? Because your code is working for me. There is no issue in your extension.

Comment: also check is you are calling this on the main thread

Comment: Try to check clipToBounds = true

Comment: Works just fine for me, if your target is on iOS 11+, you could use
`view.layer.cornerRadius = radius
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]`

Comment: With iOS 11 there is a new structure introduced named CACornerMask.              view.clipsToBounds = true
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]

Comment: You're likely calling this from `viewDidLoad` and your view's final frame has not been set yet. Call it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: @beyowulf Yea it worked!! write as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @kosas you can post your answer by yourself. Happy coding :)

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is not the right place to call ! as this method will get called many times my the UIKit